# Is MySQL ODBC 5.2a thread safe

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a multi Threaded application to access the same database.

How can I tell if any ODBC driver is Thread Safe?

In particular I'm using Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver}

Comment: I think this is wrong question. What language you are using?

Comment: @eggyal Not all ODBC drivers are thread safe, sadly, although afaik, MySQL is one of the safe ones if compiled with `enable-thread-safe-client`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I misunderstood the question; thanks for correcting me!

Comment: I'm using Powwrbasic for Windows www.powerbasic.com together with SQL Tools http://www.perfectsync.com Powerbasic is multi threading but when I try to use the multi threading mode, my app crashes. Any way to find out if the driver was compiled with enable-thread-safe-client